# App for managing multiple crypto portfolios

Tags: currencies, ios, appstore

I know I can use Blockfolio to manage/monitor multiple crypto-currencies. However I'm starting to feel the need to subdivide them by the type of asset (different risk classes, price points etc).

I have however been unable to find an app that allows me to create multiple portfolios. I really like Blockfolio in every other way though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just clone your blockfolio app with appcloner
https://steemit.com/cryptocurrency/@tektao.tips/blockfolio-a-trick-to-manage-multiple-portfolios-on-android

Comment: Thanks, great answer for Android users. I'll accept it because I wasn't that specific on platform. However I have to do something different for iOS.

Answer (score -1):

Currently I'm using vertfolio https://vertfolio.com, it’s new but simple and easy to use. You can filter by labels ( portfolio )